# parse the csv file and put the contents into table as clob object in sql plus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, clob

I have csv file and having data. And I want to store these data into a table as a clob object. I have created a table which has clob field. So, what will be the sql query. Below is the table desc.

```
SQL> desc test;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 Number                                                 NUMBER(10)
 A_DATE                                                   DATE
 CSV                                                    CLOB
 rpt_PK                                                 NUMBER
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: ORACLE-BASE has a pretty good article on how to do this: https://oracle-base.com/articles/8i/import-clob

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what format you want in this query. However, we can use package dbms_lobs to convert clob to varchar:
dbms_lob.substr( clob_column, for_how_many_bytes, from_which_byte );

so here, we can use the following SQL statement to get the content of csv:

select dbms_lob.substr( csv, 4000, 1 ) from Test;